# CardView not showing at API21

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, cardview

I was trying to make a CardView in my App but my main issue is that the cardView is not showing at my phone with API21 while it's showing it properly at the emulator (API27).

I'm not very in to android so i couldn't get where is the problem and how can i fix it.

Here is the pic of what is look's like at the Emulator and at The Phone
[image]
While here is my XML code of that layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/rellay_LOAD"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="4">


        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <!--Column 1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Column 2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <!--Column 1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Column 2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 3 -->
        <!--Column 1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Column 2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 4 -->
        <!--Column 1 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Column 2 -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardElevation="0.50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CAFFE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </GridLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellay_LOAD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights,ObsoleteLayoutParam">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="CREATE"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ` in Manifest.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya added it in my Manifest but nothing has been changed

Comment: I tested layout on Android 8.0 and its visible. On which device u are testing

Comment: @MayaMohite i was testing it on Zenfone Go Android 5.1.1